# requirements for spatial manipulation

Tags: creature-design, gravity, super-powers

In my story, I have a power system that allows humans to control certain universal forces. For example, chronomasters could control time and electromancers could control electromagnetism. Some spatial manipulators have the ability to control space (a bit similar to characters like Satoru Gojo). With this control over space, they would be able to control objects at high speeds and have pocket dimensions. The question I am asking is if there is a realistic way to accomplish at least some of these applications. For things I already know I know existence erasure can be accomplished by antimatter and that teleportation can be accomplished by controlling quantum tunneling. Also, humans are born with certain organs that allow for magic so a chronomancer would be born with an organ that could dilate time the technological level of this world is super high so you can go crazy with ways to do this lol. EDIT: I want to know how to accomplish the effects listed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know how to accomplish the effects listed

Comment: You are asking many questions at once : How do they fly? How do they create black-holes, etc. We cannot answer for everything someone with this super-power can do, as since stated there doesn't really seems to be a finite list to this power. Even if there was only 3 or 4 it is too big to fit in an answer.

Comment: can i edit to make it only two

Comment: Also, when you have a hyper-advanced society with people capable of creating black-holes and teleporting, you're already falling into the high-fantasy/science-fiction genre. In this kind of work you really rarely need to explain how it works in regards to science. That's just not the topic of interest of these worlds. If you say they have a [mutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightcrawler_(character)) that allows them to teleport, then nobody will be able to complain :).

Comment: @user357329 Yes, you can. Though... While two questions is better, one is best ;).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (a) It's asking more than one question (Needs More Focus) by asking how to explain multiple super powers. (b) It's asking how to explain the consequence of a super power without fully explaining the consequence (Needs More Details, what does it mean to "control time" or "control space" or "control electromagnetism," please provide a specific example for one super power). (\*Continued\*)

Comment: I've changed an opinion and deleted my previous comments. @Tortliena is correct, a related [meta] question is [Real facts vs worldbuilding rules](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10202/advice-real-facts-vs-worldbuilding-rules). You're not asking for help building the rules of your world. You've already done that: you created your super powers and you know what those super powers do. All you're asking for is *help describing those super powers.* It doesn't matter that science is involved. That's storybuilding, and that's off-topic.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info ill just say something about genetic engineering and gravity

Comment: Note: If you're using antimatter for "existence erasure", you're going to erase a lot of peripheral stuff from existence too.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to go on a long tangent about what i think you misunderstand. But that was a bit reductive.

I would advice you to ditch the idea of making this realistic, as one would define by physical laws. What you want is fundamentally not possible, like a Perpetual Motion Machine.

And just like a Perpetual Motion Machine, your story is not bound to our reality. Whilst in the real world, the mere notion of a Perpetual Motion Machine is grounds to reject a patent, in fiction you can have one and let the plot be driven by Thermodynamics, as did the Netflix show *Snowpiercer*. Even though a world with perpetual motion is one where thermodynamics has quit.

[image]

So how do you achieve these effects ? Magic, made up laws that apply in your world and make it internally consistent. You can sprinkle in some real world lesions we know intuitively to be true, every action has an equal and opposite reaction etc., but at the end of the day it is and will always be Magic. Which isnt bad. In fact, without Magic 99,9999% of novels would not exist and the other 0,00001% would be technical manuals.

I would suggest, instead of trying to make this work within the constraint of our modern understanding of the world, which wont work, just ditch the whole "How" and focus on what actually matters, the consequences. Nobody cares how the AR which killed MC´s gal works, but they do care for what it did.

A prime example of this is Telekinesis, it is a really nice example of magic which you can give the venire of realism by opening a grade 1 physics book. One might imagine Telekinesis to be a radiant force, so we can only push things away. Following Newton, if we push something away it will push on us as well. So whilst we might be able to deflect a 9mm bullet, that will feel like a gut punch to where ever the enabling Organ sits. We also know the energy for this force has to come from somewhere, if we want to stop a bullet with idk 500 Joule, those 500 Joule have to come from our body, so these people have to eat a lot. By just considering these basic interactions, we have taken Telekinesis which is often thought of as a game changer to a quiet limited ability that has to be used with consideration. And we have never once thought about *how* it works, just what its effects might be, assuming it just works.

Teleportation is another example. First of all, Quantum Tunneling is a statistical property and has exactly nothing to do with teleportation. And second, who cares about how it works ? Teleportation is such a good bases to consider motion. For instance, if i teleport conservation of momentum says i well, conserve my momentum. Over long enough distances my and the Earths angular momentum will differ to the point where if you for instance teleported to the other side of the world, you would shoot into the Atmosphere at Mach 1 and instantly evaporate. If i teleport out of a car, i am still moving when i arrive at the destination. Maybe people with Teleportation abilities are keep in spinning cells which make sure they cant teleport out or run the risk of flying into a wall at 200m/s.

This could go on, but i encourage you to stop thinking about the How, and focusing on the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a realistic way to do any of these things. When you start using magic or super-powers, you abandon any claim to realism or a basis in science.

The long and time-honoured tradition of comic-book super-powers could be made *less* scientifically plausible, if someone was to try. However, it would take serious effort and more scientific knowledge than comics writers use.

That's fine, for story-telling purposes. It's just a bit depressing how many people think super-powers are realistic or plausible.

Comment: Related meta-post : [Real facts vs worldbuilding rules](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10202/advice-real-facts-vs-worldbuilding-rules)

Comment: I can had wave the stuff away for the things that would make it impossible